# Debian 5 Lenny how to upgrade Python to 2.7 version to run Django app?

Tags: python, django, debian-lenny, mod-wsgi

I'm configuring Debian 5 to run my Django app. The required application is required incompatible with Python 2.5 packages. I installed Python 2.7 and created the symlink `python -> /usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python`. After I installed mod_wsgi `./configure  --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python` and added to httpd.conf `WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python`. 
Now I have a couple of problems. At first - after I manually installed setuptools and pip, at calling `pip install -r requirements.txt` of I have got an error:

> raceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>     File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in 
>     File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
>   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.0.2

**How to fix the `DistributionNotFound` problem?**

At second: in the system was installed mod_wsgi via apt-get, I manually compiled mod_wsgi 2.5 with configure flag without removing of existing version.

**The app is not fire up now, how to check, as mod_wsgi works right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set WSGIPythonHome for a start. Even in situations where it is set, you don't set it to the executable path. As per documentation you set it to what sys.prefix is for Python installation you want to use.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome

As for checking whether mod_wsgi working, read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation

and setup a WSGI hello world program first, not a complex Django system.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

and watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

Answer (score 2):

i know it does not answer your question but lenny has reached [end of life](http://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2011/msg00238.html).

if this server is internet facing you should [upgrade](http://www.howtoforge.com/upgrade-debian-lenny-to-squeeze-in-a-few-simple-steps) very very quickly to squeeze.

Comment: OK, I see. This is vps server, can I upgrade it to Squeeze?

Comment: @I159 If it's vanilla Debian, then *yes*, it can almost certainly be upgraded.  You'll want to read up on performing a `dist-upgrade`.  Whether or not your VPS provider will support this is another question, you will need to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use virtualenv to install the required Python version for your Django app without having to touch the system wide Python install?